# Android Studio Contents in Drawer Layout Not Visible

Tags: java, android, android-studio, drawerlayout, android-constraintlayout

The navigation drawer in this layout is working fine, it opens/closes with swipes and even with the button on the toolbar, and displays all the menu items correctly, which can also be selected.

However, for some reason, the "Hello, World" text view is not showing, and the entire screen is black, despite trying to set the background to white.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    tools:context="appname.coname.com.appname" >

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/global_header"
                            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            android:background="@android:color/white"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:elevation="4dp">

                            <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/global_header_title"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                                    android:textSize="22sp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/header_logo"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                                    android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />

                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/sample_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#ffffff"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:text="Hello, World!"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                    android:layout_width="240dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Your constraint layout and listview both height set to match_parent change it to wrap_content

Comment: use `navigationView ` add `ListView` child  view  of  `navigationView `

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but they both didn't resolve the issue.